# Emacs doesn't recognize C-/ in shell over ssh

Tags: emacs

I am using Emacs in shell mode through Bash in Mac Terminal, and Emacs doesn't recognize <kbd>C-/</kbd> as the undo key. It seems not to recognize <kbd>C-/</kbd> at all actually, as nothing happens when I use <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>C-/</kbd> (i.e. `describe-key` then <kbd>C-/</kbd>). Any ideas? Undoing with <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>u</kbd> is intolerable.

Thanks.

Comment: This isn't something you can fix in Emacs: your terminal isn't telling Emacs anything when you press `C-/`. You need to configure Mac Terminal to send some character sequence for `C-/`.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The problem here is that Emacs believes any modifier key (control, shift, meta etc) can be applied to any regular key.  This is true when Emacs is talking directly to the OS, but *not* when it's running inside a traditional (pseudo-)terminal, which is what you've got when you're using emacs inside ssh.  In that case, only the modified keys that map to traditional ASCII control characters can be used.  <kbd>C-/</kbd> is not one of those keys.

The good news is, because Emacs dates back to the days when ASCII terminals were the only game in town, there's another binding for `undo` that *is* an ASCII control character: <kbd>C-_</kbd> (control-underscore, aka control-shift-minus, aka U+001F UNIT SEPARATOR).

Yr hmbl crspdt was in fact not aware <kbd>C-/</kbd> did anything; he also dates back to those days, and <kbd>C-_</kbd> is what is wired into his fingers.  He cannot say whether you will find this keystroke tolerable -- it *does* involve the use of both Control and Shift -- but he suspects it's less bad than <kbd>C-x u</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Really hoping there's some kind of hack to get emacs to recognize the two-key undo.

Comment: A year and a half later, getting along fine using `C-_`.

Comment: I don't know if it's because I use a french keyboard but C-_ doesn't work for me, I can use control-shift-minus instead which is C-6

Answer (score 14):

The terminal cannot send <kbd>C-/</kbd>. All you need is a way to send an undo alias like <kbd>C-_</kbd> when <kbd>C-/</kbd> is typed. There are two relatively easy ways to do this:

1. Use [iTerm 2](http://www.iterm2.com/) instead of Mac Terminal. It remaps the key out of the box.
2. Use [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/) to remap <kbd>C-/</kbd> to <kbd>C-_</kbd> in Mac Terminal.

   1. Install [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/).
   2. Reboot.
   3. Open System Preferences > KeyRemap4MapBook
   4. Enable the following *Change Key* option (search for "control+slash"):

      > For Applications > Enable at only Terminal > Change Slash(/) Key

Answer (score 1):

emacs keybindings get wonky in terminals/consoles.  it's a royal pain, but it is *usually* fixable.  as @Zach already mentioned, the keys are sent differently when working in terminals.  the trick is figuring what is *actually* sent to emacs, and then binding that to the command you wish to execute.  [this is a pretty good](http://www.nongnu.org/emacs-tiny-tools/keybindings/index-body.html) (although old) tutorial which walks you through trying to resolve these types of issues (3.0 is where it starts to get into what you need to do).